# entry_points setting working in setup.py but not setup.cfg

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I had this in my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mycli",
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "mycli = myproject.main:program.run"
        ]
    },
)
```

After installing my package with pip I was able to run `mycli` from the shell and it executed my python app.

But I'm switching to setup.cfg.

My setup.py now looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

And my setup.cfg has this in it:

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    mycli = myproject.main:program.run
```

When installing it locally with pip mycli cannot be found. From what I have read my setup.cfg is correctly configured. Is there something I am missing that is causing the setup.cfg config to not create the entry point correctly?

After installing if I run `pip show --verbose mycli` I see the correct entrypoints in the configuration.

## EDIT

Per the comments if I run `pip show --files mycli | grep mycli` I see this:

```
Location: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages
../../../bin/mycli
```

I am able to run `./Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/mycli`

Looks like I was just missing some path settings with my pyenv setup probably not related to setup.cfg at all. Looks like this issue: [Interpreters installed via pyenv are not added to $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463930/interpreters-installed-via-pyenv-are-not-added-to-path)

Comment: `pip show --files mycli` — where is `mycli` script?

Comment: Updated my post with an edit. I appears to return a path that does not exist.

Comment: The path shown `../../../bin/mycli` is not related to the current directory, it's related to the directory in `Location:` header (higher up in the output). Check if the directory (Location + …/bin/) exists, check if there is `mycli` script in it, check the directory is in `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks I see whats happening now!

Comment: @phd could you add you tips as an answer? I googled around and had trouble figuring out what was happening. I think other users would benefit from the info shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out where `pip` installs files run `pip show --files mycli`. First note "Location:" header or extract it separately:

```
pip show --files mycli | grep -F Location:
```

The header provides the base directory (like `"$HOME"/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`). Note the relative path to the script(s). In your case it's `../../../bin/mycli`, so the absolute path should be something like `"$HOME"/.local/bin/`.

Check if the directory exists, check if there is `mycli` script in it, check the `bin` directory is in `$PATH`.