Module not found error: Imported libraries but getting this error everytime
I imported some libraries in Python and everytime I run the code i get this error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ammar/Desktop/yt-summarizer/audioyt.py", line 3, in <module>
    import librosa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'

I checked if I downloaded the libraries correctly and I did. I confirmed this by using the command pip log and got a list of libraries that were correctly downloaded.
Note: I am using a virtual environment and it is also activated. I have also tried deleting this project and recreating all over again. It just does not recognise any of my imported libraries.
I have also checked several stackoverflow posts regarding this error and implemented the solution but it doesn't correct it for me. I don't know where I am going wrong.
Edit: I used python3 -m venv env to create the virtual environment and source env/bin/activate to activate it

What is the result of "which python"? You may be using the system interpreter and not the virtual env one.

This is the result :
"python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3"

That is your system interpreter, not the virtual env one. can you edit your post and add the code on how you create the virtual env?

Just edited, can you check it

so following your command (on mac os), everything works as expected. ❯ which python3
/Users/me/env/bin/python3. What is your os? if you have an unix based os you can look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463930/interpreters-installed-via-pyenv-are-not-added-to-path

its just a macOS Monterey 12.6.3

"I used python3 -m venv env to create the virtual environment and source env/bin/activate to activate it" - and did you install the library into that virtual environment? Exactly what steps did you take, in order to try to do this?

Step 1. created the virtual env, Step2. activated it, Step3. downloaded the libraries using using pip

@stackover mac os is Unix based, you could try the accepted answer from the link I posted
